# In WordPress, how do I get the "redirect_to" URL argument to include the path & arguments of the original page for redirecting after logging in?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a custom folder called `/portal/` that takes arguments like `/portal/?id=123` or `/portal/?id=321` etc.

In the `/portal/index.php` file I included the following which automatically redirects users to the WP login if the user is not authenticated.

> include_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

If not logged in they are automatically redirected to `http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F&reauth=1`.

How do I fix the `redirect_to` argument so it includes the path and arguments? I want the redirect to look like this:

> http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fportal%2F?id%3D123&reauth=1

This way, once the user logs in, they will be redirected to the page they were trying to access in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a hack that checks for the existence of a cookie key beginning with `wordpress_logged_in_`. If the cookie key doesn't exist, then I redirect to the login page to `http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com'.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`.

Answer (score 0):

First, including `wp-load.php` isn't recommended - [Don't include wp-load, please](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) - for several reasons.

Presumably you have Wordpress configured to require a login, which is why are you are getting a redirect to the login page, and because it is happening directly from your include, you can't insert any filters to change the redirect before it's loaded, and using them afterwards is moot because the redirect will have already fired.

If this was constructed as a plugin it would be loaded by wp-load, and you would have access to the `login_url` filter, which you can use to add a redirect as in this example: http://trepmal.com/filter_hook/login_url/.

Comment: I should have been clearer. Everything running under the `/portal/` path is outside of WP. However it uses various functions from WP which is why I included `wp-load.php`. The files in the `/portal/` directory are not plugins nor javascripts thus the three cases, for not including `wp-load.php`, outlined in the link you provided don't apply. If I were to integrate everything under the `/portal/` folder into WP then I would be able to use the `filter_hook` method. I'm hoping and looking for another way.

Comment: You *are* running WP in the `/portal/` directory by including `wp-load.php`, however you don't have access to the functions in it because your code doesn't use the plugin API. There might be a way to hack it together, but...